# display 4 book details per row in image slider

Tags: php, html, css, database, while-loop

I have coded this image slider that moves the image and it's details using the cursor.

I want to  fetch data from database and display 4 books images with their details in **each row** I have tried this code but all the data have displayed in **one row only**.

Also if this does not take much of your time I want to make only 7 rows per page (28 books) and add numbers at the bottom of the page to move to the next 7 rows.

this is my try :

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="popular_causes_area section_padding">
        <div class="container"> <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-lg-12"> 
                <div class="causes_active owl-carousel">
                  <?php
                    try{
                        require('connection.php');
                        $sql1="select * from books ";
                        $rs=$db->query($sql1); 
                        $db =null;
                        } catch(PDOException $ex) {
                           die ("Error Message ".$ex->getMessage());   }
                 $i=0;
                 while ($books = $rs->fetch()){
                  $i++;
                  $bpic = $books[2];
                  $btitle= $books[3];
                  $bq= $books[4];
                  $bstatus = $books[5];
                  $bdesc = $books[6];
                  $bnumber = $books[7];
                  $bcity = $books[8];
    
                 if ($i % 3 == 1) {
                    echo "<li>";   ?>

                    <div class="single_cause">
                        <div class="thumb">
                         <?php
                          if ($bpic == "" ) {
                           echo "<img src='img/default-image.png'  
                            height=450px'>"; 
                          } else {
                           echo "<img src='img/$bpic' placeholder='nooooo' 
                            height=450px  alt=''>"; 
                                               }?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="causes_content">
                            <div class="balance d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <span>Tell:<?php echo $bnumber; ?> </span>
                                <span><?php echo $bcity; ?> </span>
                            </div>
                            <h4><?php echo $btitle; ?> </h4>
                            <p><?php echo $bdesc; echo "<br> 
                            condation:".$bstatus; ?> </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>

                                <?php   
                                  } ////end of first if 
                                  if ($i % 3 == 0) {
                                     echo "<li>";   ?>
                        <div class="single_cause">
                        <div class="thumb">
                            
                       <?php
                         if ($bpic == "" ) {
                         echo "<img src='img/default-image.png'  height=450px'>"; 
                        } else {
                        echo "<img src='img/$bpic' placeholder='nooooo' height=450px  alt=''>"; ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="causes_content">
                        <div class="balance d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            <span>Tell:<?php echo $bnumber; ?> </span>
                            <span><?php echo $bcity; ?> </span>
                        </div>
                        <h4><?php echo $btitle; ?> </h4>
                        <p><?php echo $bdesc; echo "<br> 
                        condation:".$bstatus; ?> </p>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </li>
                        <?php
                            } //end of second if 
                            } // end of while ?>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[This image shows what I got (all the data in one row instead of 4 books per row !):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFgF7.jpg)

**image slider code :**

```
    <div class="popular_causes_area section_padding">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="causes_active owl-carousel">
    <div class="single_cause">
                        <div class="thumb">
                            
<?php
if ($bpic == "" ) {
    echo "<img src='img/default-image.png'  height=450px'>"; 
} else {
    echo "<img src='img/$bpic' placeholder='nooooo' height=450px  alt=''>"; 
}
?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="causes_content">
                            <div class="balance d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <span>Tell:<?php echo $bnumber; ?> </span>
                                <span><?php echo $bcity; ?> </span>
                            </div>
                            <h4><?php echo $btitle; ?> </h4>
                            <p><?php echo $bdesc; echo "<br> condation:".$bstatus; ?> </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Why the unassociated `</li>` in various places

Comment: I have tried to put the the slider in list and table but non of them works :(  @RiggsFolly